# Java: jsp+hibernate with eclipse. sample applications?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I mostly code in PHP and Python.

Java experience: All the basic stuff i learnt in college.

Preferred IDE: Eclipse

I installed hibernate tools for eclipse and i did manage to connect to mysql and got a hello world application up and running.

My Problem:-
I don't know how i am going to start out with small cms for starters using jsp and hibernate.

Comment: take a look at http://jforum.net/ ... it is open source java based discussion board ... not something that you are looking at ... but it shows how java code and database access and other stuff are organized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [JSP_and_Hibernate_Tutorial_using_Eclipse](https://matrix.senecac.on.ca:8443/wiki/javaEE/index.php/JSP_and_Hibernate_Tutorial_using_Eclipse)

Comment: do i have to do all this just to fetch some data ? wo this is a lot of code.

Comment: Must needed files are: POJO classes, Hibernate configuration file[hibernate.cfg.xml], Utility class and table's config files[ *.hbm.xml] and your logic.

Comment: Do you have links to other tutorials like this?

Comment: Try this : http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I would definately use [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) for getting your head around this. It will quickly and easily get an application up and running.

Matt Raible provides loads of quick start videos and posts on how to get running as well as different configurations of persistence layer technologies, presentation frameworks etc.

It also has support and tutorials for integration with Eclipse and IntelliJ

Certainly worth a look.